# Prove that relationship is symmetric and transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $xRy$ iff $4|(x+3y)$ is symmetric and transitive? The relation is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Symmetry**

Need to prove $4|(y+3x)$

\begin{align*}
x + 3y & = 4k\\
y + 3x & = 4k - 2y + 2x\\
2(y+3x) & = 8k - 4y + 4x\\
2(y+3x) & = 4(2k-y+x)\\
\frac{y+3x}{4} & = \frac{2k-y+x}{2}
\end{align*}

Therefore, $4|(y+3x)$.

Therefore, symmetric? Is this valid to conclude from what I've done?

**For transitivity I need to show**

$4|(x+3y)$ AND $4|(y+3z)$ IMPLIES $4(x+3z)$.

So I have the 2 equations

\begin{align*}
x+3y & = 4a\\
y+3z & = 4b
\end{align*}

Add them together:
\begin{align*}
x+4y+3z & = 4a + 4b\\
x+3z & = 4a + 4b - 4y\\
x+3z & = 4(a+b-y)
\end{align*}

Therefore $4|x+3z$.

Therefore transitive.

Are my proofs for symmetry and transitivity valid?

Comment: Try to understand what pairs of elements $(x,y)$ actually satisfy the relation (do some examples). That should make it clearer why this is symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Right so does 4|(x+3y) imply 4|(y+3x)

Comment: Then you need to see if xRy and yRz imply xRz.

Comment: Hint: $\ 4\mid y\!+\!3x\iff 4\mid y\!-\!x\,\ $ since $\,\ y\!+\!3x = y\!-\!x + 4x\ \ $

Comment: Is my way of proving it valid though?

Comment: Your argument for transitivity is certainly valid.  However, for symmetry, you would have to show that $x - y$ must be even.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x+3y=4k$. Then $y+3x = 4(x+y)-(x+3y)=4(x+y-k)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ 4\mid y\!+\!3x\iff 4\mid y\!-\!x\,\ $ since $\,\ y\!+\!3x = y\!-\!x + 4x\ \ $

But $\,x\equiv y\iff 4\mid y\!-\!x\,$ is clearly symmetric and, furthermore, is transitive by

$\qquad x\equiv y\equiv z\,\Rightarrow\, 4\mid y\!-\!x,z\!-\!y\,\Rightarrow\, 4\mid z\!-\!y+y\!-\!x = z\!-\!x\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv z$

**Remark** $\ $ The equivalent simpler relation is the relation of *congruence* modulo $4.\,$ Such [congruence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) play a fundamental role in number theory.